# Deleting contacts from mac contacts application with no Phone number

Tags: macos, mac, contacts

Is it possible to delete contacts from mac contacts application which have no phone no? Or export only those contacts which have a contact?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Contacts or Address Book, you can make a Smart Group (`File` --> `New Smart Group...`) that has the criteria `Phone` `is not set` which will collect all the contacts without phone numbers. Then you can view the members of this group and delete those contacts (or do whatever you want with them).

Comment: bbird: i love you so much, it hurts! this has been plaguing me for year and i could never figure out a way to get rid of the 6,000+ contacts that i had.

Comment: Smart Groups are awesome. In Mail, Finder, Contacts - the utility is fantastic for this sort of maintenance.

Comment: Brilliant, except, that some of my contact have a Phone number in a field that I smart groups do not consider being a Phone field. I'm just trying to say, 2x check before deleting.

Comment: This does not work in Sierra. I created a Smart Group for Phone = not set and Email = not set and it includes plenty of contacts with phone numbers and email addresses.

Comment: @MichaelKupietz I haven't looked at this in a while but testing it out briefly it looks like contacts with multiple "cards" (aka Unified Contacts) confuse the smart group criteria. It may also have something to do with seebach's comment.